# Why some university asks for recomendation letter directly to be sent from the recommender?

Tags: phd, recommendation-letter

When I was applying for PhD I was considering Germany, UK, Austria and Switzerland in my search for a position. So far, I found that each university/region has their own policies in application submission process.

For instance, I found that most of the Swiss universities ask for a direct recommendation letter from the recommender and it is not acceptable to submit it as a general one and it is only acceptable if it's sent directly from the recommender's institute email to the target university. In contrast, in Germany where applying now at a higher ranking university than the Swiss one, professors, and universities are more flexible and accepts them as a general one, so no need to be specifically produced for the particular university.

I tried hard to find a place in Swiss universities, but I ended up rejected with no response from my previous professor as it considered time consuming for him, and I don't blame him since general recommendation letter is enough in other universities.

Do universities that ask for such a thing consider them self better than the others and will lead them to better candidates?

The question is, why such universities make it hard for the student who apply for PhD? Is a general recommendation letter (I have 4 letters from different professors) from your previous professors where they indicate positivity about the candidate enough for such a PhD application?

Comment: Differences in policies do no suggest difference in status. Maybe its just a Swiss thing.  BTW what is the difficulty, besides spending 2 minutes, for a professor to transform a general rec.letter to one specifically addressed to a particular university?

Comment: Also, could u please clarify what do you mean with "general ones"? You mean recommendation lettres that _you_ submit on your application and are addressed _to whom it may concern_?

Comment: @PsySp being a professor with a very busy schedule will not help. Filling up the forms to two/three different swiss universities and then send them will be frustrating. And yes , General one means as you indicated.

Comment: But that's the job/duty/responsibility of an academic adviser. They can't simply say "oh i'm bored".

Comment: @PsySp but it is really bored... Filling forms for several students who applies to different universities is too boring since others accept them as general one.

Comment: I do not sympathize with it. I agree its tedious and borderline boring but if a prof. agreed to provide recommendation letter, that's it, there are no excuses. It's part of the duties.

Comment: @PsySp some universities ask for a form to be filled, others asks to be filled with each course that student took and in which semester took it with his notes, and most important thing that they associated this document with deadline.. so having a lazy professor will affect your dream job!

Comment: In some cases, they may think the recommender may be more honest in his evaluation, if he believes the candidate cannot see the letter.

Comment: In the US, there are services that help professors draft, keep track, and submit different versions of recommendation letters to different institutions. This makes that work easier for the professor, but this is also to ensure that the student doesn't get to see the letter and so the letter is actually taken much more seriously that way. Are you sure that in Switzerland that they don't use similar systems?

Comment: Your actual question is why Swiss universities require letter too be sent by the recommender, while German ones don't

Comment: @PsySp: "But that's the job/duty/responsibility of an academic adviser."; "It's part of the duties." - there have been some other discussions related to this topic elsewhere on this site. It seems that the degree of obligation to write letters of recommendation varies considerably by culture, covering the full spectrum from "definitive duty" to "generous voluntary favour".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I meant: in case the prof. _agreed_ to provide a rec. letter, then it's his duty to be consistent.

Comment: @PsySp: Hmm, well ... I keep what I initially promised to do, but I'm not always cooperative when I suddenly see myself drawn into also doing all kinds of follow-up tasks popping up once the initially promised task is done.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I get your point but agreeing to provide rec. letter should prepare you of such processes. This is not an unknown practice.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper promising and not delivering, especially in such sensitive task, is highly irresponsible in my opinion.

Comment: @PsySp: "This is not an unknown practice." - but it is not the only one, not generally the default one in all places, and thus not necessarily the implied one when originally asking for the favour. "promising and not delivering" - nowhere did I suggest that, so that is beside the point. On the contrary, I wrote: "I keep what I initially promised to do"

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Fair enough. I misunderstood your "but I'm not always cooperative". I think we agree.

Answer (score 4):

By forcing the letter to be sent directly from the institutional email of the Professor, the university makes sure it is a truthful recommendation and not a modified or faked one. Such practice of faking documents in unfortunately happening in any recruitment environment, not only academia.
Even worse and common practice in academia, my own phd adviser asked me to write my own recommendation letters because he lacked time, and he just signed them. 
Such practice as described in your message partially prevent this.

Comment: "Such practice as described in your message partially prevent this": such practice surely _don't_ prevent that".

Comment: At least you are sure of the identity of the senders, so for sure it prevents the case where people make up previous experiences

Answer (score 0):

Its common to have writers write general letters (To Whom it May Concern) tailored for particular kinds of applications (i.e. PhD programs in the field of your major). Some programs, such a fellowship programs, involve funding for a very specific topic and want letters tailored for your participation in that particular program. When you're applying to PhD programs, the same letter usually suffices (I'm writing from experience as a US academic, so I could be wrong about the rest of the world). But the applicant is very rarely allowed to submit their own letter. The letter should come directly from your writer to ensure that the writer can write honestly. This is standard practice in the US, and its also my experience in the UK. To avoid asking your writer to submit dozens of letters, you can usually use a dossier service like interfolio to upload the letters. Sometimes it doesn't work, but then you're only asking your writer to manually submit a handful of letters.